# It's possible to use conditionals on config.yml on symfony?

Tags: symfony, parameters, config, multi-tenant, saas

One question: it's possible to use conditionals on config.yml of symfony?

I have this:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@XXXBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

And I want this:

```
imports:
     if (....) {
    - { resource: parameters1.yml }
     } else {
    - { resource: parameters2.yml }
     }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@XXXBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

Comment: No that is not possible. What exactly do you want to accomplish this way?

Comment: @Gerry I have SaaS multitenant App and I wanted to set differents parameters for each client. I Solved it arranging the files like: app/config/tenant1/..., app/config/tenant2/... loading it by kernelApp :) It works fine!

Comment: Be aware that a container is only compiled once, so it will always use the same parameter values if you load configuration files dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @Gerry I tested it in and it works fine :S

Comment: I don't know what your specific solution is, and maybe my statement does not apply to your solution, but it is still valid :)